# Read property of an annotation in another

Tags: java, annotations

If I declare an attribute from my class this way:

```
@Order(value=1)
@Input(name="login")
private String login;
```

and the definition for `@Input` is this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Input {

    String type() default "text";
    String name();
    String pattern() default "";

    String tag() default "<custom:Input ordem=''/>";

}
```

Is there any way to read the property `value` from `@Order` and use for the property `tag` from `@Input`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Accessing the `login` variable’s annotation value from within the constant `default` value of `Input.tag`? How is the annotation `Input` supposed to even know that there will be an `@Order` annotation at the same field, not to speak accessing its values?

Comment: I am thinking of a sort kind of "common zone", where the annotations of one same field could share some informations between themselves. I am trying work now with the answer from @KumarAbhinav below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways of reading metadata such as annotations,fields and classes is Reflection.You can use reflection to read meta -data of an annotation too.

**This will work only if `@Order` annotation has RuntimePolicy of Runtime `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`**

Note :- Annotations also are Class objects.Each annotation is a special type of interface and interfaces are also treated as `java.lang.Class` Objects.

```
Field loginVariaable = .../// get your login attribute from your Class Object using reflection 
Order order = loginVariaable.getAnnotation(Order.class)
int orderValue = order.value();

Input inputObject = loginVariaable.getAnnotation(Input.class)
String inputName= inputObject.name();
```

Generics helps you in getting the Annotation object without casting to Annotation Object.Also ,note that all annotations implicitly extends `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the good old compile-time constants:

```
static final int MEANINGFUL_NAME = 1;

@Order(value=MEANINGFUL_NAME)
@Input(name="login", tag="<custom:Input order='"+MEANINGFUL_NAME+"'>")
private String login;
```

The rules for compile time constants still apply when providing values to annotations, so you can calculate constants using other constants and you may place the constants in other classes and use static imports. They may even get placed into the annotation just like into other interfaces which may come handy when they are some kind of standard values for the annotation.

```
@interface Example {
  int COLD = -1, WARM = 0, HOT = 1;
  int value() default WARM;
}
```

…

```
@Example(Example.HOT)
```

or

```
import static stackoverflow.Example.*;
// …
@Example(HOT)
```

Comment: Ok, this is pretty close what I want. One question: I try do what you do (in `int value() default WARM;`), but using a String value, and I get the error `the value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression`. this only can be done with `int`?

Comment: This should work with `String`s as well. Make sure that the variable is `final` and immediately assigned and that the expression is composed of constants only. See [JLS §15.28. Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)